# KINECT in C#: Translate forward motion to up motion on the screen

Tags: c#, kinect

In a nutshell, I have the Kinect picking up my motion and I have created a nice skeleton so that I can easily see my forward/backward/side to side movements.  I want to take these forward/backward/side to side movements and translate it to up and down or side to side motion on the screen.In other words, say I have the left foot moving forward and backward from the camera, I want to translate that as a dot moving up and down respectively. Is there a way to simple transpose from YZ plane to XY plane? I want to have both the forward and up motion displayed on different parts of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly your problem.

If you'll look into playerSkeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position (where playerSkeleton is a Skeleton object obtained from the skeleton frame) you'll see that you have the X, Y and Z coords of the joint.
You can also do something like:

```
DepthImagePoint jointDepthPoint = DepthFrame.MapFromSkeletonPoint(playerSkeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position);
```

and you get the value of the resulted pixel, resulting the depth value.

In rest is just math ... you just scale the value.

Let's say your depth value is between 128 and 256 and you want to scale that on a (0, 0) to (480, 0) interval (like an horizontal line)

new_value = (480 - 0) * your_value/(256 - 128)

So you can draw your dot on (new_value, 0)